# Cron Job timing

Tags: cron

Lets say

```
0   0,12    *   *   * command
```

is what you write a cron job, which runs twice a day on 00hour and 12th hour.

How to write to do cron job twice a day but lets say on 2pm and 2am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron runs on a 24 hour clock starting from 0 as midnight and 23 as 11 pm. As such you'd simply have to replace `0,12`   with `2,14`

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Cron Job Script Calculator**: 
http://www.csgnetwork.com/crongen.html

Or try **Crontab Generator**:
https://crontab-generator.org/